# Is there a way to check if a specific Node from a XML-File contains a comment and if it does to read the comment?

Tags: c#, xml, list, comments

I want to read all comments from specific Nodes and put them into a List in C#.

My Code is:

```
List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
List<string> valueList= new List<string>();

var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load("xmlfile.xml");

var result = xmldoc.SelectNodes(/manuel/chapter-ref/chapter/chapter-ref/chapter/block/procedure/step/action/table/tgroup/tbody/row/entry/p/formfield/@field_id);

foreach(XmlNode item in result){
keyList.Add(item.Value)
}
```

This way I can get every field_id from the formfields and put them into the keyList. Some formfields contain a comment and some don't. I want to add those comments into the list valueList and if the formfield doesn't contain a comment I want to add "no value" into the list. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: can you share your ``XML`` file content?

Comment: The XML-File is a generated file and is very big. 6600 lines. The formfield looks like this: <formfield y.validity.allowed="true" font-family="courier" border-thicknes="small" width="20mm" typ="text" font-size="12" border-color="none" y.id="ID_d520a944aa82bec9ac1402ce2bfce057" field_id="101-01" y.validity.mode="positive">
                                                <!--0,040-->
                                                <quickinfo>X,XXX</quickinfo>
                                             </formfield>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select comments in XPath using `foo/bar/comment()`

Since you already call `SelectNodes` towards the formfield I suggest changing the XPath and add an if statement checking for the comment node.

```
List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
List<string> valueList= new List<string>();

var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load("xmlfile.xml");

// Removed '/@field_id'
var result = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/manuel/chapter-ref/chapter/chapter-ref/chapter/block/procedure/step/action/table/tgroup/tbody/row/entry/p/formfield");

foreach(XmlElement item in result)
{
    var nd = item.SelectSingleNode("comment()");
    if (nd != null) valueList.Add(nd.InnerText);
    else valueList.Add("no val");

    keyList.Add(item.GetAttribute("field_id")); // Changed to GetAttribute
}
```

Comment: Doesn't GetAttribute only work with an XmlElement? I get an error wich says XmlNode does not contain a definition for 'GetAttribute'.

Comment: yes but your selection is sure to be XmlElements, just change the XmlNode type in the foreach to XmlElement.

Comment: Thank you mate! Didn't see you changed it to XmlElement. It works perfectly fine just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Using xml liinq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication159
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var comments = doc.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(XComment)).ToList();            
         }
    }
}
```